# Paho MQTT throws Exception

Tags: java, mqtt, paho, iot

I have downloaded an example in Java in order to demonstrate Paho MQTT.

```
 public class Thermometer {

    public static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883";

    public static final String TOPIC = "xyz.abc";

    private MqttClient client;


    public Thermometer() {
        try {
            MemoryPersistence per = new MemoryPersistence();
            String clientId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            client = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, clientId, per);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Problem occurs when I run it, it locates at `client = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, clientId, per);` with

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>       at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.(MqttClient.java:170)
>       at mqtt_pub.Thermometer.(Thermometer.java:26)
>       at mqtt_pub.Thermometer.main(Thermometer.java:65)

I have found that @throws IllegalArgumentException if value of QoS is not 0, 1 or 2 but in class MemoryPersistence they did not mentioned. Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a quite old version of the paho mqtt library - so, which version are you using ?

Comment: I used paho 1.0.1 version. but I read its documentation in http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/index.html?org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/IMqttClient.html, maybe it is mqttv3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your take a look at the [source code](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java/+/v0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttClient.java) of `MttqClient` you can see that the `uuid` can only have a length of max 23 char. Looks like the uuid is longer:

```
if (clientId == null || clientId.length() == 0 || clientId.length() > 23)  
{
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

`UUID.randomUUID().toString()` returns a string with the length of 36 char;